# Where can I find my lost query?

Tags: pgadmin

I've written a BIG query in pgAdmin III, and I didn't execute/save it. pgAdmin III crashed. Is there an autosave feature in pgAdmin? Is it possible to find this query somewhere?

**Note:** The file `C:\Users\*****\AppData\Roaming\postgresql\pgadmin_histoqueries.xml` doesn't contain my query.

Comment: Searching "pgAdmin autosave" I only found a feature request from almost 7 years ago. I don't know if it was implemented.

Comment: @ZoharPeled please tell me, is "pgAdmin autosave" a file? where can I find it?

Comment: No, Autosave is feature. A lot of text editors will save the documents you are currently working on automatically every x time, so if it crushes, you could restore these documents up to the last autosave. I'm not working with postgresql, so I don't know for sure, but from what I've found online, this feature is not implemented on pgAdmin, meaning your query is resting in peace with the socks that didn't make it out of the washing machine...

Answer (score 0):

You may find them in Aginity Query History by doing Alt+H or looking at the View -> User Query History

This should provide a history of all the queries you ever made